# Inheritance , how can i make two classes share the same base class contents?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I have an Abstract Class operations that inherits from VAR Class , which then all the operations derived class(out,sleep,Add) inherit from the operations  class. FSM Class inherits from Var also, so That I want one instance of VAR class inside my program.

I am trying to make vector < pair< string, int>> var as a shared data between the FSM class and the Operations class and its deviates . I initialized the var in the main through the FSM class .

Each time we call the exist function in VAR through Class operation , it returns it doesn't exits cause it is empty ! How can I overcome this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
class VAR
{
public:
    vector<pair<string, int>> var;
    VAR()
    {
        cout << "created VAR" << endl;
    }

    ~VAR(){ cout << "Destrioed  VAR" << endl; }
    void createVar(string x,int y)
    {
        pair<string, int>t;
        t.first = x;
        t.second = y;
        var.push_back(t);
    }
    int getVarValue(string x)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i<var.size(); i++)
        {
            if (var[i].first == x)
            {
                return var[i].second;
            }
        }
    }
    void setVarValue(string& x, int y)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<var.size(); i++)
        {
            if (var[i].first == x)
            {
                var[i].second = y;
                i = var.size();
            }
        }
    }

    bool exits(string& name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<var.size(); i++)
        {
            if (var[i].first == name)
                return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
};
class operations : virtual public VAR
{
public:
    operations()
    {
        cout << "operations created" << endl;
    }
    ~operations()
    {
        cout << "operations   Destroied" << endl;
    }
    void virtual excute() = 0;

};

class Out :public virtual operations
{
public:
    string s;
    Out(string xx = "") :s(xx)
    {
        cout << "Out created" << endl;
    }
    ~Out()
    {
        cout << "Out   Destroied" << endl;
    }
    void virtual excute()
    {
        cout << "out Class" << endl;

        if (exits(s))
        cout<<"it never reach here, WHY !"<<endl;
    }
};
class Add :public  virtual operations
{
public:
    string s;
    Add(string ss = "") :s(ss)
    {
        cout << "ADD created" << endl;
    }
    ~Add()
    {
        cout << "Add   Destroied" << endl;
    }
    void virtual excute()
    {
        string ex1 = s.substr(s.find('=') + 1, s.find('+')), ex2 = s.substr(s.find('+') + 1);
        if (exits(ex1))
            cout<<"it never reach here, WHY !"<<endl;
        else
            result = atoi(ex1.c_str());

        if (exits(ex2))
            cout<<"it never reach here, WHY !"<<endl;

    }
};
class state
{
public:
    vector<operations*> instructionList;
    string name;
    void exec_all()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < instructionList.size(); x++)
            instructionList[x]->excute();
    }
};

class transition
{
public:
    vector < pair<state, vector<pair<state, int>>>> trans;
    static int currentState;
};
class FSM :public virtual VAR, public virtual transition
{
public:
    FSM()
    {
        cout << "FSM" << endl;
    }
    void intialize()
    {
        createVar("X", 1);
        createVar("Y", 5);
    }
};
void main()
{
    FSM x;
    pair<state, vector<pair<state, int>>> p1;
    pair<state, int>p2;
    x.intialize();

    p2.first.name = "b";
    p2.second = 3;
    p1.first.name = "a";

    p1.second.push_back(p2);
    x.trans.push_back(p1);

    x.trans[0].first.instructionList.push_back(new Add("X=X+Y"));
    x.trans[0].first.instructionList.push_back(new Out("X"));
    x.trans[0].first.exec_all();//wrong output cause exist() returns false

}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show what you want.

Comment: Any reason that `Wait` doesn't inherit virtually as other classes ?

Comment: cause wait doesn't need the variables, and it is ok  even if we made it to inherit from VAR.

Comment: It sounds like you're misunderstanding something. You don't have one `VAR` instance - every one of your instances that inherit from `VAR` is a `VAR` instance. They all have their own  unique `var` members; all are distinct from the one in `x`.

Comment: How can i unite these Vars using Inheritance?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg i edited it as you wanted

Comment: You might want to read about [object composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) and [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

Comment: This code is still far from minimal. And it doesn't quite compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal complete example looks something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class VAR
{
public:
  int var;

  virtual ~VAR()
  {}

  void setVar(int n)
  {var=n;}
};

class Out :public VAR
{};

class FSM :public VAR
{};

int main()
{
  FSM x;
  x.setVar(5);

  Out OP;

  if (x.var==OP.var)
    cout<<"it reaches here now" << endl;
  else
    cout << "it fails" << endl;

  return(0);
}
```

And one way to fix it is like this:

```
class VAR
{
public:
  static int var;
  int var;

  virtual ~VAR()
  {}

  void setVar(int n)
  {var=n;}
};

int VAR::var=0;
```

Comment: why make both: static int var

Comment: it worked fine , after i declared the vector as static. Thanks a lot @Beta